# Wordpress Ninja Forms hook after paypal payment is completed?

Tags: wordpress

I use wordpress ninja forms plugin with paypal express extension. I need to know what is the hook after paypal payment(successful one), because I want to send some data to a server. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ninja_forms_checkout_success` is the action hook that runs after a successful payment.

`ninja_forms_checkout_fail` runs when a payment fails.

Comment: thank you, I made it with ninja_forms_post_process but ninja_forms_checkout_success is better I think

Comment: Can you guys please provide some examples/documentation links for this action hook? curious to know what parameters can be returned from PayPal to our action hook...